# In a timeseries dataframe how to perform daily computations and store in same column?

Tags: python, dataframe

My dataframe has time-series data for many days. I want to perform daily computations and store them in the same column.

For example:

```
Dataframe
----------------------------
Timeseries              A 
2019-01-24 14:03:00    10 
2019-01-24 14:04:00    20
2019-01-24 14:05:00    15
2019-01-25 14:06:00     9
2019-01-25 14:07:00    18
2019-01-25 14:08:00    12
```

I want to create a new column called per unit A `puA` which contains value A/Amax, where Amax is max value among A on that day. The snippet of my code is given below:

```
dates_list = ['2019-01-24','2019-01-25']  #Extract uniques dates list
    for i in dates_list:
        df['puA'] = df['A'].loc[i]/df['A'].loc[i].max()
```

My present output is:

```
Timeseries             nA            puA
2019-01-24 14:03:00    10            NaN
2019-01-24 14:04:00    20            NaN
2019-01-24 14:05:00    15            NaN
2019-01-25 14:06:00    n9     9/18 = 0.5
2019-01-25 14:07:00    18    18/18 = 1.0
2019-01-25 14:08:00    12    12/18 = 0.6
```

It is storing only for last date, not all off them.

I want output as

```
Timeseries              A     puA
2019-01-24 14:03:00    10    0.50 
2019-01-24 14:04:00    20    1.00
2019-01-24 14:05:00    15    0.75
2019-01-25 14:06:00     9    0.50
2019-01-25 14:07:00    18    1.00
2019-01-25 14:08:00    12    0.60
```

How to achieve this output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I see you have found your answer, your solution seems very ugly. Let me show you a cleaner and more pandas like approach.

Firstly you will have to create a new column called date.

```
df['date'] = df['Timeseries'].dt.date ##
print(df)

          Timeseries   A        date
0 2019-01-24 14:03:00  10  2019-01-24
1 2019-01-24 14:04:00  20  2019-01-24
2 2019-01-24 14:05:00  15  2019-01-24
3 2019-01-25 14:06:00   9  2019-01-25
4 2019-01-25 14:07:00  18  2019-01-25
5 2019-01-25 14:08:00  12  2019-01-25
```

Now apply a group by function on the date column and find the max value for each date

```
grouped_df = df.groupby(df['date']).max().reset_index()[['date', 'A']]
grouped_df.columns = ['date', 'max_A']
print(grouped_df)

         date  max_A
0  2019-01-24     20
1  2019-01-25     18
```

Now you can use the [df.merge()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) function to join 2 dataframes on a column

```
merged_df = df.merge(grouped_df, on='date')
print(merged_df)

           Timeseries   A        date  max_A
0 2019-01-24 14:03:00  10  2019-01-24     20
1 2019-01-24 14:04:00  20  2019-01-24     20
2 2019-01-24 14:05:00  15  2019-01-24     20
3 2019-01-25 14:06:00   9  2019-01-25     18
4 2019-01-25 14:07:00  18  2019-01-25     18
5 2019-01-25 14:08:00  12  2019-01-25     18
```

Now for each row in the dataframe you have `A` and `max_A`. Simply create a new column by dividing `A/max_A`

```
merged_df['puA'] = merged_df['A']/merged_df['max_A']
print(merged_df)

           Timeseries   A        date  max_A       puA
0 2019-01-24 14:03:00  10  2019-01-24     20  0.500000
1 2019-01-24 14:04:00  20  2019-01-24     20  1.000000
2 2019-01-24 14:05:00  15  2019-01-24     20  0.750000
3 2019-01-25 14:06:00   9  2019-01-25     18  0.500000
4 2019-01-25 14:07:00  18  2019-01-25     18  1.000000
5 2019-01-25 14:08:00  12  2019-01-25     18  0.666667
```

This my friend is the pandas way. It does not involve any ugly for loops and hardcoded strings.

Comment: You can always remove the unwanted columns as you go. I have left them there for a better explanation. Plus looping over pandas dataframe is always a bad idea. It is alwasy better to use numpy operations.

Comment: Your answer did help me. Thank you very much. Compared to my for loop solution, your solution was fast and quick. No errors.

Answer (score 0):

After trial and error I found the answer:

```
dates_list = ['2019-01-24','2019-01-25']  #Extract uniques dates list
    for i in dates_list:
        rows_of_interest = [ind for ind, a in enumerate(df.index) if a.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") in i]
        df['puA'][rows_of_interest] = df['A'].loc[i]/df['A'].loc[i].max()
```

My output is:

```
Timeseries              A     puA
2019-01-24 14:03:00    10    0.50 
2019-01-24 14:04:00    20    1.00
2019-01-24 14:05:00    15    0.75
2019-01-25 14:06:00     9    0.50
2019-01-25 14:07:00    18    1.00
2019-01-25 14:08:00    12    0.60
```